# Gradle: Can't pass argument to class in plugin

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I tried as per [example](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:mapping_extension_properties_to_task_properties) in, and simplified it to just "message".

```
class GreetingPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        def extension = project.extensions.create('greeting', GreetingPluginExtension, project)
        project.tasks.create('hello', Greeting) {
            message = extension.message
        }
    }
}

class GreetingPluginExtension {
    def String message = "aa"

    GreetingPluginExtension(Project project) {
        message = project.property(String)
    }

}

class Greeting extends DefaultTask {
    @Input
    def String message = project.property(String)

    @TaskAction
    def testCoverageVerification() {
        logger.quiet("Message is")
        logger.quiet(message)
    }
}

apply plugin: GreetingPlugin

greeting {
    message = 'Hi from Gradle'
}
```

When I run `./gradlew -q hello`, I got

```
Message is
value: null
```

I expect it to be

```
Message is
value: Hi from Gradle
```

Why did my String from the greeting fail to pass in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it's quite easy to explain. The plugin (hence the task creation and variable value assignment) is applied and evaluated **before** the extension block is evaluated. So the task is created even before the extension's value is set. From the link you provided:

> The extension declaration in the build script as well as the mapping
>   between extension properties and custom task properties occurs during
>   Gradle's configuration phase of the build lifecycle. To avoid
>   evaluation order issues, the actual value of a mapped property has to
>   be resolved during the execution phase.

To make it work you can change the plugin declaration to this:

```
class GreetingPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        def extension = project.extensions.create('greeting', GreetingPluginExtension, project)
        project.tasks.create('hello', Greeting) {
            doFirst {
              message = extension.message
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However it doesn't make much sense - so don't use it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I manage to resolve my issue by directly getting it from `project.greeting.message`

```
@TaskAction
def testCoverageVerification() {
    message = project.greeting.message
    logger.quiet("Message is")
    logger.quiet(message)
}
```